# My log file deleted after reboot with probe

Tags: java, tomcat8, probe

I am using probe along with tomcat. My application which is deployed in tomcat 8.5 use log4j for its logging.

This is `Log4j.properties` configuration :

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL = DEBUG, file
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type = TRACE, file

# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=${catalina.base}/logs/my-app.log
log4j.appender.file.Append=true
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy.ActiveFileName=${catalina.base}/logs/my-app.log
log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=${catalina.base}/logs/archive/my-app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz
```

Everything is fine and i could fine my logs, but when the server restart i lost everything.
It seams like probe delete the log file after reboot
Am i missing something in the configuration on my application or even in the prob side?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
#outputs to Tomcat home
log4j.appender.file.File=${catalina.home}/logs/my-app.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

can you check above code?
put all properties in your log4j properties file

Comment: Thank you for your response but I went to redirect all my logs to my_app.log not to catalina.out of the tomcat server

Comment: then you can use your project directory path to store the logs

Comment: for example `log4j.appender.file.File=../webapps/logs/a.log`